# Why is browser showing td's larger than my specified width property?

Tags: css

td width is 162px even though style="width:25px" for td and th

I've put this in my css file

```
table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

table.narrow th, td {
    width:50px;
}
```

It doesn't work. The last one there is supposed to take a table with class="narrow" and make all its descendent th and td elements 50px wide. And chrome shows Matched CSS Rules:

```
.narrow th, td { width: 50px; }
```

So chrome is reading it and ignoring it? Or CSS is just idiotic? Or I am? Why can't CSS just do what you tell it, like a normal programming language?

SO, I tried putting style="width:25px" right in the 1st column td AND th tags and still, doesn't work. Chrome shows:

```
element.style { width:25px; }
```

but it won't tell me why the hell it's displaying it at 162px.

Anyone have any clues?
Thank you.

---

Edit: Kolink gave me the clue I needed. Form text fields inside the  tags were causing a large minimum width.  I added this style to shrink the table:

```
.narrow input{
  width:80px;
}
```

It reduced the width of all the inputs inside the class="narrow" table and hence reduced the width of the table.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Set `table-layout: fixed;` on the table's styles. Otherwise table layout is loose and `width` is treated more like `min-width`.

Comment: Hmm I see you got three up votes but this did not work for me. table-layou: fixed; is showing up in the browser. No effect on cell width.

Comment: Is the content of the cell wider than the desired width, with no breaking possible? Maybe try `word-break: break-all` or `overflow: hidden` on the cells.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks. I was displaying values in disabled form fields. I guess their default size is 155px in Chrome. I added another style to my css file for them and now it FINALLY works!
.hw3p3 input{
 width:80px;
}

Answer (score 3):

Your definition is for all TDs

```
table.narrow th, td {
    width:50px;
}
```

You have to repeat the affected element in the enumeration

```
table.narrow th, table.narrow td {
    width:50px;
}
```

Comment: Really? I guess that makes sense but it did not occur to me.